# How to define function types in component's props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to destructure a component props in type script
i'm using `react-redux`

the component takes an function as a action via `connect` in props

action takes an object with this type

```
  interface ContactFormTypes {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    EmailAddress: string;
    PhoneNumber: string;
    Message: string;
  }
```

so here is how the action works

```
export const sendEmail = (contactData: ContactFormTypes) => {......}
```

it is a void function since it only sends request to API

in the connect function i pass the action into component's props

```
export default connect(null, { sendEmail })(Contact);
```

now i want to destructure that action in props what type should i use and is this a good approach for doing that??

```
const Contact = ({sendEmail:  ?????  })=>{
   
   return <div> ........

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your interface first

```
    export interface ContactFormTypes {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    EmailAddress: string;
    PhoneNumber: string;
    Message: string;
  }
```

Try this in your Contact component:

```
    import React, { FC } from 'react' //Functional component Type
    import {ContactFormTypes} from 'yourfile'
    
//Define a new interface for this component props
//define sendEmail as a function with (args: type) => return type
    interface Props {
        sendEmail: (contactData: ContactFormTypes) => void
    }
    
    
    const Contact: FC<Props> = ({sendEmail}) => {
         return (...)
    }
```